# Using batteries to power op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

So pretty much I have a ~4.5V power supply from 3 AA batteries, that I want to power an op amp (LM358P).

The reason I'm doing this is so I can boost the AC signal from a piezo sensor, the problem is, every time I set it up correctly (I think), without the signal inputs, it gets really hot, I've read the data sheet and kinda get whats going on.

I'm also not too sure how to hook up the signal, do I connect one cable to ground and one to the non-inverting, or do I connect it to Vcc-?

Thanks for the help y'all.

Comment: You can use batteries to power an Opamp, but it should not get hot, and how you hook up the signal depends on the circuit you have built.

Comment: You should connect the battery positive terminal ($4.5\,V$) to $V_{+}$ and the other one (battery negative terminal) to GND ($V_{-}$).

Comment: If it gets hot it is connected wrong and/or damaged. | If DIP package: pin 1 has a 'dot' indentation on the package. Pin numbers increase anticlockwise starting at pin 1. Place flat on a surface pin 1 at left, Pin 4 at right. | Pin 4 is ground = battery negative . Pin 8 (diagonally opposite pin 4) is Vcc = battery positive. | Circuit schematic editor included in this site's editor  is easy to use and allows you to input a circuit diagram.

Comment: Note the input leads should never be left disconnected, as static electricity will probably damage the component. If the piezo can be disconnected, then you need some protection at the input otherwise it will likely be damaged.

Comment: You should post a diagram of your circuit.  Your description sounds like you have it connected incorrectly, but without a diagram it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether it is the battery heating or the IC is heating. If the IC is heating there is a good chance the +ve termal of battery is conneced to the ground pin of the IC and -ve terminal of the battery is connected the the +v pin of the IC.